# Render recursively a nested data in React

Tags: javascript, wordpress, reactjs

How would i go about rendering a menu with nested `<ul>` items with an an unknown amount of children in react from an object like in the following example?

```
[
  {
    title: "Top level 1",
    slug: "top-level-1",
    children: [
      {
        title: "Sub level 1",
        slug: "sub-level-1",
        children: [
          {
            title: "Sub Sub Level 1"
            slug: "sub-sub-level-1"
          }
        ]
      }
      {
        title: "Sub level 2",
        slug: "sub-level-2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    title: "Top level 2",
    slug: "top-level 2"
  }
]
```

Comment: Two questions: 1. Have you attempted to do this by yourself? 2. Is the depth of nesting a known factor?

Comment: yes i've tried a few different things. I'm able to render the top level items using `.map()` but i cannot seem to get my head around how to render the children. I would ideally like the solution to be able to render children regardless of depth

Comment: If you want to be able to traverse an object of unknown depth you will need to use recursion. You'll want to make a function that takes an object and an accumulator as an argument. The function will check for `.children` on the provided object and invoke itself with each child object as an the argument, don't forget the accumulator! If the provided object does not have a .`children` property it is a leaf node and you can generate you component with it's information. The accumulator is what the recursive function will used to build up the final collection as it goes.

Comment: thanks! that makes sense - i guess my real question is how would i write such a function that conditionally stores components/markup that i can then return later in my component. In vanilla js, i would just store the markup as strings then output - however this approach doesnt seem to work in react.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/76gpQkOgy)

You just have to recursively call Menu component for its children to display and pass as a data prop.

```
let data = [
  {
    title: "Top level 1",
    slug: "top-level-1",
    children: [
      {
        title: "Sub level 1",
        slug: "sub-level-1",
        children: [
          {
            title: "Sub Sub Level 1",
            slug: "sub-sub-level-1",
            children: [
              {
                title: "Sub Sub Level 2",
                slug: "sub-sub-level-2"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        title: "Sub level 2",
        slug: "sub-level-2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    title: "Top level 2",
    slug: "top-level 2"
  }
];

const Menu = ({data}) => {
  return (
    <ul>
      {data.map(m => {
        return (<li>
          {m.title}
          {m.children && <Menu data={m.children} />}
        </li>);
      })}
    </ul>
  );
}

const App = () => (
  <div style={styles}>
    <Hello name="CodeSandbox" />
    <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen {'\u2728'}</h2>
    <Menu data={data} />
  </div>
);
```

Comment: This is fantastic, is there a simple way i could pass down a slug prop to children components to form eg 'top-level-1/sub-level-1/sub-sub-level-1' ?

Answer (score 4):

You could recursively Render the component for nested data which has variable depth.

Sample Snippet.

```js
var data = [
  {
    title: "Top level 1",
    slug: "top-level-1",
    children: [
      {
        title: "Sub level 1",
        slug: "sub-level-1",
        children: [
          {
            title: "Sub Sub Level 1",
            slug: "sub-sub-level-1"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        title: "Sub level 2",
        slug: "sub-level-2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    title: "Top level 2",
    slug: "top-level 2"
  }
]

const MyComponent  = (props) => {
     if(Array.isArray(props.collection)) {
         return <ul>
               {props.collection.map((data)=> {
                   return <li>
                      <ul>
                        <li>{data.title}</li>
                        <li>{data.slug}</li>
                        <li><MyComponent collection={data.children}/></li>
                      </ul>
                   </li>
               })
               }
         </ul>
     }
     return null;
}

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
           <MyComponent collection={data}/>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

P.S. The snippet contains formatting errors, but I am sure you will be able to rectify that. Snippet was to give an idea of the approach